# Using jQuery, iterate rows in html table, set class on cell

Tags: jquery

I have this html table:

```
<table class="relativeTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="relativeTableTR">
            <td class="relativeTableTD">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    ...
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="relativeTableTR">
            <td class="relativeTableTD">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="12">Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <input id="12" type="text"/>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="relativeTableTR">
            <td class="relativeTableTD">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="12">Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="te"></textarea>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="relativeTableTR">
            <td class="relativeTableTD">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            Radiobtns
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <table class="input-list radio-buttons">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <label>
                                        <input id="Radio1" type="radio" value="[no]~[no]">
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <label>
                                        <span>nei</span>
                                    </label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How to iterate all the rows (tr) in the table, and find cells containing an input or textarea element. Matched cells (td) should be marked with a style='padding-top: 2px;'

In my example the last 3 relativeTableTDs (and not the first) should be selected.

Something like this:

```
$("tr.relativeTableTR").each(function()
{
    TODO: find td of class relativeTableTD containing input or textarea, and set style...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `:has` and `css`. `:has` accepts a selector and only selects the element which has the selector specified, in this case `:input`, which handles `textarea` and `input`, among others.

```
$('.relativeTableTD:has(:input)').css('padding-top', '2px');
```

Also, if there are more styles to be set, then just put them in a class and add it to the collection using `.addClass('className')`